# how to save selectedindex of radiogroup to sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I'd like to save the selectedindex of a radiogroupt to sharedpreferences but I haven't a clue on how to do it. Can anyone give me some tips how to do it? THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the sample code below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RadioGroup radioGroup;

private static final String SELECTED_INDEX="SelectedIndex";

private OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangedListener=new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        saveSelectedIndex(checkedId);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangedListener);
    RadioButton rbtn=((RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(getSelectedValue()));
    if(rbtn!=null){
        rbtn.setChecked(true);
    }
}

private int getSelectedValue(){
    SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return pref.getInt(SELECTED_INDEX, -1);
}

private void saveSelectedIndex(int value){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putInt(SELECTED_INDEX, value);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already added your radiogroup, are you able to read it and know how to use sharedpreferences?

If so, I recommend you to override onPause() in your activity. There, you can read value of your radiogroup and save it to sharedpreferences.

Then, if needed, override onResume() to read from sharedpreferences and update UI.

Comment: @Ali 's answer and mine are complementary. You can add his code to onPause().