# Radiogroup value doesn't save in sharedpreference in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have want to checkble radiobutton value in my second activity.
i have also use RadioGroup and sharedpreference.

but first Radiobutton value get in my second activity. so sharedpreference not saving the radiobutton value.

please show this code and help me how can i get?

```
 rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiotype);    

         rbtn=((RadioButton)rg.findViewById(getSelectedValue()));
         if(rbtn!=null){
                rbtn.setChecked(true);
            }
         rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                savePreferences(RemainderType_Toggle, checkedId);

            }
        });
    }   

private void loadSavedPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

         TypeToggleValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(RemainderType_Toggle,     R.id.radionoti);


        if (TypeToggleValue == R.id.radionoti) 
        {
            rbtn.setChecked(true);
        } 
        else 
        {
            rbtn.setChecked(false);
        }       
    }   

    private int getSelectedValue(){
        SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return pref.getInt(RemainderType_Toggle, -1);
    }
    private void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

SecondAcityvity.java

here i want the selected radiobutton value.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);      

        TypeToggleValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(RemainderType_Toggle,     R.id.radioalarm);

        Log.d("TypeToggleValue", String.valueOf(TypeToggleValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to refer your `RadioButton` in reference to your `RadioGroup`. Simply you can access it without reference.

Change your below line

```
 rbtn=((RadioButton)rg.findViewById(getSelectedValue()));
```

as below

```
 rbtn=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
```

Comment: But i have multiple radio button so which radio button id pass in    rbtn=(RadioButton)findViewById( ?);

Comment: I have also refer this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145512/how-to-save-selectedindex-of-radiogroup-to-sharedpreferences